# Why is specific nuclear activity (Bq/kg) not considering the surface area (cm^2)?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation, nuclear-engineering

I have some basic questions regarding nuclear radiation:

How come the specific activity (Bq/kg) only depends on the mass number and halftime of the emitter?

**Therefore, the emitted ions (let's say by an alpha source) are a function of the mass number, halftime and the specific energy of the emitter, right?**

Why the surface area is not part of the equation? How do the alpha particles penetrate from the the "inside" of the emitting material to the surface?

Thanks a lot,
Daniel

06-06-2018: Added a sketch to explain my question.[image: Alpha emitter embedded in base material- Only surface exposed]

Comment: $\alpha$ particles are easily blocked, so only those emitted very close to the surface are likely to leave the radioactive body. The kinetic energy of the blocked alphas becomes heat, a spectacular example of this is [Plutonium-238](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plutonium-238).

Answer (score 8):

The [specific activity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_activity) is the number of decays per second, not the amount of radiation emitted from some object. Therefore the absorption of emitted radiation within the object is not relevant - the same number of nuclei decay per second regardless of whether the decay products escape the sample or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot and also thanks to @Farcher . I added a sketch now. Did I understand it well that only about 50% of the near surface layer radiation potentially exits the surface (where it potentially creates ions in air), the other 50% of the near surface layer will go into bottom direction and “disappear”?
All other alpha particle created by the volume of the alpha emitter will not be able to leave the emitter, because they are either blocked by the alpha emitting material itself or by the lead? Therefore, a thin layer of alpha emitter would create as much ions as the bulk material?

Comment: @Daniel That near-surface layer is very thin: typical alphas can be blocked by a sheet of paper, or by a smoke particle, which is exploited in smoke detectors based on Americium-241. OTOH, as dmckee points out, many alpha emitters also emit some gamma, which isn't easily blocked. That's why that big block of lead is a Good Idea.

Answer (score 5):

The specific (meaning per unit mass)  activity relates to the number of decays per unit time (number of alpha particles emitted per unit time) and it depends on the number of unstable nuclei in the sample and the half life.

It is highly likely that given the short range of alpha particle the number of alpha particles which escape from the source is less than that number.

To measure the specific activity is therefore likely to be difficult for alpha emitters.
One way is to try and use a very thin sample so that absorption of the alpha particle is minimised.

Comment: *"To measure the specific activity is therefore likely to be difficult for alpha emitters."* Many lines are accompanies by photons which cam be counted fairly easily. But pure alpha lines exist (I'm looking at *you* $^{210}\mathrm{Po}$) and are, indeed a royal pain.

Comment: @dmckee Thank you for the information about the gamma emission which I did not think about.